# Optimize Drupal Composer Workflow via Gitlab

Tags: composer

I have the following workflow for one of my product based on Drupal 8:

I use three custom private dependencies via composer ( two modules , one theme) , a lot of contrib modules and obviously drupal core. We git-ignore core drupal, contrib and custom modules/theme delivered via composer.

When I commit to one of my **custom modules/theme**, I have a lot of operations to do to update all  projects :

- I commit and push my modification to the custom module/theme
- I have to composer update project, one by one, to the new release, via composer update
- I commit, one by one, a composer.lock
- I have to composer install project in live stage ( not really great ).

Others issues :

- My colleague must composer install when they are back to the project to get the update.

Environnement:
We use Gitlab.com for all projects that use our product. We have access to Gitlab CI/CD but it's not used at this time.

How optimize this workflow ? Any tools ? Gitlab CI/CD examples ? We can reconsider the full workflow too.

Comment: Eventually I used git subtress to share modules and theme into multiple drupal instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats an interesting question.

- "I commit and push my modification to the custom module/theme". (Obviously you cannot skip that part)
- Then you will update your module version number.
- Then you will push your branch to gitlab repo.
- That should start a CI pipeline.

This pipeline will do everything you have to do manually for now :

- Getting your branch code
- Running composer install (as your module version number has changed, this would trigger an module download, depending on how you had set the updating strategy, this could requires some tweaking).
- Commiting composer.lock, vendors and modules to a build (it could be a branch commit, or a compressed package)
- Running tests if you have any (you should)
- Pushing the branch, the tag or the package to your integration platform

You need to consider your gitflow and your environment to start writing a gitlab CI pipeline. I'm using Gitlab so I cannot give you example.

You probably need to create or use a Docker image on which your code will run, and with the appropriate tooling (composer, obviously, maybe npm if you have SCSS, curl, gzip, whatever...).

Local environments will still need to run composer install manually. You could use docker and script the building process locally but that's a different subject.

Comment: Thanks and how other projects that used the updated dependencies are triggered when I update the dependency ?

Comment: Well, I think you will have to start pipelines for those. Each branch has its own pipeline so you could sort of propagate an update to some explicit dependencies. IRL, if you update a dependencies, it's the responsability of each projet using it to update or not. In your case, as you manage all aspects, you have to decide how ro replicate this behavior. Either in each pipeline, or in a custom script outside the project.